# Extracting specific value from a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, text-formatting

I have a sample file like this.

```
Zone A
Total Population 500 unit
Total Area 150 sq. unit
Zone B
Total Population 600 unit
Total Area 200 sq. unit
Zone C
Total Population 400 unit
Total Area 100 sq. unit
```

How can I extract zone name followed by its population like following way?

```
A
500
B
600
C
400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a trivial task for awk.

```
awk '/Zone/{print $2} /Population/{print $3}' file
```

If current line has `Zone` in it, prints the second field; for `Population`, prints the third.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 awk '/Zone/ {print $2;getline; print $3}' file

A
500
B
600
C
400
```

- `getline` reads the next line after the current line.

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to extract something which doesn't appear in the immediate next line, for example in this case zone name followed by its area?

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
grep -Po 'Zone \K.*|[0-9]+(?= unit)' file
```

- `-P` enable perl-compatible regular expressions
- `-o` print only matching parts
- `Zone \K.*` match any characters (`.*`) following `Zone` plus a space character. Everything before `\K` is not printed (zero-width positive lookbehind).
- `|` or
- `[0-9]+(?= unit)` matches one or more digits followed by a space character and `unit`. The `(?= unit)` is a zero-width positive lookahead assertion and its pattern (space character and `unit`) is also not printed.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` command substitution:

```
$ sed -En '/Zone/N; s/Zone ([A-Z]+).+ ([0-9]+).*/\1\n\2/p' file
A
500
B
600
C
400
```

---

To cover case *"Zone name" + "Area value"*:

```
$ sed -En '/Zone/N;N; s/Zone ([A-Z]+).+ ([0-9]+) sq.*/\1\n\2/p' file
A
150
B
200
C
100
```